# Call js function in php

Tags: javascript, php

Need some help here. I have a main page index.php with a simple js function, say function1() which upon clicking, opens a page, say test.php as a pop-up window, which includes contents from another page p1.php. I need to condition it so that when user clicks function2(), it opens same page test.php but with different content from page p2.php.

index.php code is below;

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
   <!--
   function function1(theURL,winName,features) { 
   window.open(theURL,winName,features);
   }
   //-->
   <!--
   function function2(theURL,winName,features) { 
   window.open(theURL,winName,features);
   }
   //-->
   </script>

<td>
<p><a href="#" class="left-content" onclick="function1('test.php','','scrollbars=yes,width=auto,height=600')">Page 1 contents</a></p>
</td>

<td>
    <p><a href="#" class="left-content" onclick="function2('test.php','','scrollbars=yes,width=auto,height=600')">Page 2 contents</a></p>
    </td>
```

I am making the following conditional statements in page test.php

```
<?php

    $a = include ("p1.php");
    $b = include ("p2.php");

    if(isset($_GET['<script>function1()</script>']))
        echo $a;

    else if(isset($_GET['<script>function2()</script>']))
        echo $b;
?>
```

The result I get is that the contents of both p1.php and p2.php are reflecting in test.php (our pop-up window). How do I condition it so that only p1.php content is reflected onclicking function1() and p2.php content is reflected onclicking functions2(). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where are `function1` and `function2` even defined? - By the way, I'm surprised you get either p1.php or p2.php with that PHP code, seeing as both those conditions would never be true

Comment: yes they are defined in index.php file as - function1(theURL,winName,features) {  window.open(theURL,winName,features);   } function2(theURL,winName,features) {  window.open(theURL,winName,features);   }

Comment: so, they are PHP functions ... you need to think how PHP works ... it pre-processes the page, then sends HTML to the browser ... the PHP functions are not accessible to javascript

Comment: function1() and function2() are js functions to open popwindow.

Comment: can you show them please - in the question ... and, there's no difference in what they send to the server, so how would the server know which button was pressed

Comment: I have added the js function. How the server would know which button / link was clicked ----- that's the question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a query/search string to the URL in the request i.e. like `?name=value`

you don't need two different JS functions by the way - in fact, you don't need any JS function for what you are doing

index.php

```
<td>
    <p><a href="#" class="left-content" onclick="window.open('test.php?v=1','','scrollbars=yes,width=auto,height=600')">Page 1 contents</a></p>
</td>
<td>
    <p><a href="#" class="left-content" onclick="window.open('test.php?v=2','','scrollbars=yes,width=auto,height=600')">Page 2 contents</a></p>
</td>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    $a = include("p1.php");
    $b = include("p2.php");

    var page = isset($_GET['v']) ? $_GET['v'] : 0;
    if (page == "1")
        echo $a;
    else if (page == "2")
        echo $b;
?>
```

Comment: Well. Had to do minor changes in your code, but concept wise it works!!! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: replace var page with $page / remove $a = include... / replace echo $a with include "p1.php" and so on. This will reflect specific page on clicking the link in index.php containing the php function (query/search string to the URL).

Comment: Yes. My PHP is rusty